# Grails plugin error : class path resource cannot be resolved

Tags: grails

I have the following error ( java.io.FileNotFoundException ) in my log file.
The plugin's path doesn't exist :

```
   class path resource [E:/projet/toolprod/fichiers_install/toolprod/target/work/resources/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

Perhaps, it's due to old things ?
How can I fix it ?

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
    2015-09-14 12:04:56,575 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [E:/projet/toolprod/fichiers_install/toolprod/target/work/resources/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:412)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources(PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java:286)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.getPluginBundles(PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.java:152)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.context.support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.afterPropertiesSet(PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:625)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:468)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:156)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.initializeContext(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:188)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:126)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoaderListener.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5490)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    2015-09-14 12:04:56,610 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full         Stack Trace:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [E:/projet/toolprod/fichiers_install/toolprod/target/work/resources/plugins/webxml-1.4.1/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade the grails version (2.5.0) to Grails 2.5.1 and the error disappears.